# VBA to simulate ActiveX Control Click

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Using `Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()` , we can run a macro as we go to SlideShow Mode.
My objective is to recognise KeyPress and run macros accordingly during the SlideShow. For that, I can utilise this code:

```
Sub CommandButton1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If (KeyCode = vbKeyRight) Then 'Your code goes here
End Sub
```

In this case, I would have to click on `CommandButton1` for the KeyPress to be recognised.
We need an ActiveX Item to make use of `MSForms.ReturnInteger` and we cannot directly make use of the ActiveX with `Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()`

Is there any way to collect KeyPress throughout the entire presentation without having to click on any ActiveX Buttons? Also, even if we click on it, the KeyPress is collected only for that specific slide and not in the subsequent slides.

I was trying to "Set Focus" on the CommandButton but that was futile. I tried tampering with `keybd_event` but was unable to fulfill the objectives of recognising keypresses and running an if-then condition after that. Also, `SendKeys` do not function in PowerPoint.

Is there any way to simulate the click of a CommandButton using VBA?

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/utilising-commandbutton1keydown-across-all/2dc33f71-501a-454a-adbc-7c69db532254